# Best practice to keep dynamic logo image in angular app (MongoDB or S3 or filesystem)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, amazon-s3

This is an web app for our clients, there is an option to upload logo as well as app profile which is stored on Mongodb and other file upload options are on S3.

Which is the best practice to keep my dynamic logo on memory(mongo or s3)? If it's mongo, is there any problem to make it as **base64** and keep it on mongo? How to use base64 which will work in all browsers?

Comment: Nope, no problems whatsoever. You can store as files in filesystem, you can store in mongo as files, you can store in mongo as byte stream, you can store in mongo as base64 string. Choose whatever you like.

Comment: whats the best practice for logo image? other junk of files uplaod, yes we can go for s3. But with profile/company details, logo also should include on mongo, right?

Comment: Why? What difference would it make?